# Windows: how can I let the child process read the input anonymous pipe without closing it?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, pipe

As per subject I'm trying to develop a simple piped parent/child program.
Main purpose of this program is to keep the child process alive and use `std::cin` and `std::cout` to communicate between parent/child processes.

On Linux all of this works quite well.

On Windows I've been following the example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx) and there's one peculiar difference with Linux: one has to invoke

```
CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr)
```

To write to the child pipe and flush it. This has the side effect to close the pipe, thus terminating my *in-connection* to the child process.
I've also tried to use [FlushFileBuffers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364439(v=vs.85).aspx) but it doesn't work.

Any idea how can I *flush* the buffer without having to close the *anonymous pipe*?

Below sources of both *Parent* and *Child* processes.
If the code of the *parent* process is basically the one in the example above:

```
// IN_Wr_ is initialized as below with bInheritHandle=TRUE
::CreatePipe(&IN_Rd_, &IN_Wr_, &saAttr, 0);
// and
::SetHandleInformation(IN_Wr_, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)
// When I spawn the child process I do
STARTUPINFO         siStartInfo = {0};
siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO); 
siStartInfo.hStdError = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
siStartInfo.hStdOutput = OUT_Wr_;
siStartInfo.hStdInput = IN_Rd_;
siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
...
// then in order to write to std::cin
const DWORD reqSz = static_cast<DWORD>(std::strlen(request));
DWORD       written = 0;
while(true) {
    DWORD   curWritten = 0;
    if(!WriteFile(IN_Wr_, request + written, reqSz-written, &curWritten, NULL))
        throw std::runtime_error("Error on WriteFile");
    written += curWritten;
    if(written == reqSz) {
        // all written, done
        break;
    }
}
::FlushFileBuffers(IN_Wr_);
// only when I do this CloseHandle then the child process
// is able to read data
::CloseHandle(IN_Wr_);
```

this *child* code is a simple *echo* server, along the lines of:

```
buif[2048+1];
while(std::cin) {
    std::cin.read(buf, 2048);
    const auto  rb = std::cin.gcount();
    buf[rb] = '\0';
    std::cout << buf << std::endl; // this does flush
}
```

Comment: well, first, linux does not have that MSDN function: `CloseHandle()`.  Then any output stream can be flushed using the syntax:: `fflush( FILE *stream );`

Comment: There's no need to do *anything* to flush the pipe.  The example closes the handle specifically to notify the child that it is finished, not because the child otherwise wouldn't be able to read the data.  (If you're using runtime library routines, obviously you'll need to flush those buffers.  But you don't need to do anything at the OS level.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Without *closing* the pipe, the child process *blocks* on that stream (`std::cin`) indefinitely on Windows (tested on Windows 7). Try sending ~10 bytes. What happens is that those stay buffered until or the buffer is full or is *flushed*. Alas `FlushFileBuffers` doesn't work, hence the only way is to `CloseHandle`. Which force *flush* but also closed the communication channel.

Comment: @user3629249 Please elaborate more.

Comment: Please show the code that isn't working.  I'm not very familiar with `std::cin` but it *ought* to work.  Assuming you're sending a string, did you remember to include a linefeed at the end?  (I'm guessing that `std::cin` waits for a linefeed by default; if not, substitute whatever terminator is appropriate.)

Comment: with no posted code, with some discussion of Linux, the question will be answered only with opinions.   Suggest post code that shows the problem, is short, and cleanly compiles.   Note: the best/perhaps ony way to actually 'flush' a pipe is for the reader to read all the bytes in the pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
std::cin.read(buf, 2048);
```

It's doing exactly what you've asked it to: waiting until it has read 2048 characters or reaches the end of file.  You're not sending 2048 characters, so nothing happens until the server closes the pipe, which counts as the end of file in this context.

Instead, you should be using something like `getline(s, 2048, '\0')` which will stop reading when it sees a null character.  (And, of course, you will need to modify the sender so that it writes that null character at the end of the string.)

Alternatively, you could use the native API: `ReadFile` has the semantics you seem to be wanting.  Ideally you would use a message-mode pipe, which is designed precisely for this sort of use.

Comment: Funnily enough in Java, the similar API `BufferedReader.read` works similar to the low level APIs (`read` and/or `ReadFile`).

Answer (score 0):

The article here might be helpful: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/190351. It has a section on flushing problems when printf is used to send data to the redirected pipe, which seems to be done in your case. The suggested solution is to use fflush(NULL) to flush the C run-time IO buffers.

Comment: Not an unreasonable suggestion, but I don't think this is the problem.  If it were, then calling CloseHandle wouldn't have worked, since that doesn't affect the runtime library's output buffers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is a MSFT implementation of `std::cin::read` (and even `fread(..., ..., ..., stdin)`).
If instead of relying on:

```
// C++ API
while(std::cin) {
    std::cin.read(buf, 2048);
    ...
// or also "C" API
int rb = 0;
while(0 < (rb = fread(buf, 2048, 1, stdin))) {
    ...
```

I do

```
// Low level Win32 "C" API
while(::ReadFile(hStdin, buf, 2048, &rb, 0)) {
    ...
// or also low level unix-like "C" API
int rb = 0;
while(0 < (rb = _read(0, buf, 2048))) {
    ...
```

The above example just works fine (funnily enough, the call to [FlushFileBuffers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364439(v=vs.85).aspx) is not even *needed*).

Comment: That's because `istream::read` reads the specified number of characters unless you reach end of file, which in the context of a pipe means when the other end of the pipe is closed.  `ReadFile` on the other hand has a special case: it exits when a write operation completes on the other end of the pipe.  (If using istream::read works on Linux, *that* may be an implementation error, since the C++ standard does not appear to permit the read to exit prematurely except on end of file.)